# Unable to return a variable

Tags: java, return

Im trying to return the variable val and print the future value out without using a print statement, the complier says it's good but wont return the value.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class FutureValues{

  public static Scanner scan = new Scanner( System.in);
  public static void main(String[] args){
    double currentAmount = scan.nextDouble();
    double rate = scan.nextDouble();
    double year = scan.nextDouble();
    FutureValue(currentAmount,rate,year);
  }
  public static double FutureValue(double p, double r, double y){

    double rate = r/100.0;
    double fv = p*(1 + rate);
    double val = Math.pow(fv,y);
    return val;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please explain _print the future value out without using a print statement_.

Comment: you're calling: `FutureValue(currentAmount,rate,year);` from main - but you're not saving the returned result anywhere (nor printing it).

Comment: "print ... without using a print statement" sounds like this belongs to https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/

Comment: You have to use `print` in some form. You could probably wrap the stdout in some other stream wrapper, and define your own `print`, but at *best* it would be doing the same thing.